# object disappearing when geom_rect is added

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data:

```
Distance   Average    Standard.error     CI
   -300  0.9338864     0.01409078   0.02761792
   -150  0.9339457     0.02097350   0.04110805
    -50  0.9495119     0.01359277   0.02664183
     50  0.8588988     0.03599673   0.07055359
    150  0.8531203     0.03047781   0.05973651
    300  0.7945437     0.05874081   0.11513199
```

I am creating a graph in ggplot2 the code I have so far is:

```
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Average - CI, ymax = Average + CI), width = 5)+
  geom_point(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average), stat = "identity", 
             point = 21, fill = "white")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-300,300,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.6,1,0.05))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour= "black"))
```

I want to add a grey background to the graph from -300 to 0 on the x-axis so I created this data frame:

```
background <- data.frame( xstart = 300, xend = 0, col = "grey")
```

and then added this line to the script for the graph:

```
geom_rect(data = background, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                                 fill = col), alpha = 0.4)
```

so the code for the graph now looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average))+
  geom_rect(data = background, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf,    ymax = Inf,
                                   fill = col), alpha = 0.4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Average - CI, ymax = Average + CI), width = 5)+
  geom_point(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average), stat = "identity", 
             point = 21, fill = "white")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-300,300,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.6,1,0.05))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour= "black"))
```

However now I get an error message when I try to produce the graph that says:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Distance' not found
```

The graph is produced fine before the `geom_rect` line is added why does adding that line make 'Distance' disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because `geom_rect` is taking the `x` and `y` aesthetics from the initial `ggplot` call (even though it doesn't need or understand them) and cannot find them in `background`.

Why not just feed in `xstart`, `xend` etc in directly rather than creating `background`?

```
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 300, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
                                   fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Average - CI, ymax = Average + CI), width = 5)+
  geom_point(data = Test, aes(x = Distance, y = Average), stat = "identity", 
             point = 21, fill = "white")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-300,300,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.6,1,0.05))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour= "black"))
```

Note - I took the 'fill' out of the 'aes' in `geom_rect` so that the fill colour is interpreted as the literal colour 'grey', rather than a factor which *happens* to have the value "grey" (and then ggplot will use whatever default colour scheme it usually uses for factors). I think you could actually take *everything* out of the `aes` call to `geom_rect` there.

Comment: That is a much better way of doing it. I realise my was was a little convoluted. Thank you.